# npmjs fs security issue

Tags: node.js, express

I want delete image/file in my nodejs/express js project. We were do this with unlink() method of **fs** package. But now this package(fs) has security problem in npmjs website. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The fs module on npmjs is not the built in module. You don’t need an external module for fs.

Comment: thanks so much. Your comment solve problem. I got it. thanks.